# Multiple choices selected not working

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with a multiple checkBox list (choice list is prepared dynamically). I want them to be selected from the beginning (so that user can uncheck them). I have prepared an array with choices and checked_choices, but during the form rendering only the first checkbox is selected. Any suggestions about how to fix it?

```
$choices = array();
$choices_check= array();
foreach($user[0]->getShops() as $shop)
{
    $choices[$shop->getId()] = $shop->getName();

    $choices_check[] = true;
}
//return $this->render('GLPolicyBundle:Policy:tmp.html.twig', array('entities' => var_dump($choices_p)));

$searchby = array();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($searchby)
        ->add('shop', 'choice', array('choices' => $choices,

                                    'multiple' => true,
                                    'expanded' => true,
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'data' => $choices_check)                
            )
        ->add('date_from', 'date', array('data' => $date_from))
        ->add('date_to', 'date', array('data' => new \DateTime()))
        ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data needs to be an array who's values are the keys of the choices that you want selected.

Changing $choices_check[] = true to the following should do it.

```
$choices_check[] = $shop->getId();
```

Note that after you POST the form, $form->getData() is the same format.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to set checked attribute in the Twig view :

> {% for shop in form.shop  %}
>
> {{ form_label(shop) }}
>
> {{ form_widget(shop, { 'attr': {'checked': 'checked'} }) }}
>
> {% endfor %}